# In custom Project Template with Visual Studio 2017 Community - error "The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved"

Tags: visual-studio, project-template

I try to create a custom project template in VS 2017 Community. Whenever I try to create a project from this template I get the error "The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved" when I try to access the .cpp file (the only source file in the project).
Moreover, the source file is not named after the project name, but like it was in the original project based on which the template was created.
I followed several tipps on the web, but still cannot really figure out how to edit the .template file of the project template zip file to get the template working. Can anybody help?